# How to force model attribute with certain data type

Tags: magento

There is "date_stamp" field in the database table. Field type is bigint(20).
I get this value in my code.

```
 $dateStamp = $model->getDateStamp();
```

I need $dateStamp to be int or long. But It's string. How can I force it to be int or long?

Comment: can you just use (int)$model->getDateStamp(); ??

Comment: `int()` may very easily break values which are valid for MySQL `bigint`.

Comment: I believe Magento has way to describe types for model attributes, am I right? Can I extend model to make this functionality? So task is to set type for magic-fields of php class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I need quick solution, I have maden new function in the model.

```
public function getFloatDateStamp(){
    $dateStamp = (float) $this->getDateStamp();
    return $dateStamp;   
}
```